# Mulitiple mouseevent use in one time in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I am trainee front end developer and I am  working on some demo.
It is working for **onclick** mouse event but it is not working for **both onclick and onmouseover**. I need an `onclick` option and also an `onclick + mouseover` option.

Here is my html file:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyStyle.css">
  <script src="myScript.js"></script>

  <title>Main page</title>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

  <canvas id="can" height="100" width="100"></canvas>
  <br />
  <input id="btn" type="button" value=" + " onclick="incr()">
  <input id="btn" type="button" value=" - " onclick="decr()">
  <select id="hundred" onchange="setHundred()">
    <option value=0> 0 </option>
    <option value=100> 100 </option>
    <option value=-100> -100 </option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is my Javascript file:

```
var can, ctx, hun, n = 0;

function init() {  
  can = document.getElementById("can");
  ctx = can.getContext("2d");
  hun = document.getElementById("hundred");

  showN();
}

function showN() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(64, 255, 64)";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.font = "24pt Helvetica";

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height, 99);
  ctx.fillText(n, can.width / 2, can.height / 2);
}

function incr() {
  n++;
  showN();
}

function decr() {
  n--;
  showN();
}

function setHundred() {
  n = hun.value;
  showN();
}
```

---

and the css file:

```
#btn, #hundred { 
  font: larger bold;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

canvas {
  background-color: black; 
  border: 1px solid rgb(64, 255, 64);
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

---

My question is:

> **how I use onclick and both onclick and onmouseover for `+` & `-` ?**
>
> **Also it would increment if click pressed**

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried adding onmouseover event in your buttons? i don't really understand the problem.

Comment: You should be using [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of setting the properties in the HTML.

Comment: @Dencio ... sir i tried it.. `<input id="btn" type="button" value=" + " onclick="incr()" on(click|mouseover)="incr()" >`

Comment: @ChathurangaNanayakkara Did you actually write the property like `on(click|mouseover)`? If so, that's your problem...

Comment: @ChathurangaNanayakkara No I mean just add onmouseover to button element.

Comment: @Dencio.. Sir i want to make it with both onmouseover and onclick at same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By all means, do you mean this kind of implementation? where onclick and mouseover have the same approach?

(Updated code below)
I understand now your question, for that case I am using onmousedown and onmouseup + interval implementation.

Please check below:

```js
var can, ctx, hun, n = 0;
var timer = null;

function init() {
  can = document.getElementById("can");
  ctx = can.getContext("2d");
  hun = document.getElementById("hundred");

  showN();
}

function showN() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(64, 255, 64)";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.font = "24pt Helvetica";

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height, 99);
  ctx.fillText(n, can.width / 2, can.height / 2);
}

function incr() {
  n++;
  showN();
}

function decr() {
  n--;
  showN();
}

function setHundred() {
  n = hun.value;
  showN();
}

function setTimer(type) {
  timer = setInterval(function() {
     if (type == 'incr') {
       incr();
     } else {
       decr();
     }
  }, 200);
}

function removeTimer() {
  clearInterval(timer);
}
```

```css
#btn, #hundred { 
  font: larger bold;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

canvas  {
  background-color: black; 
  border: 1px solid rgb(64, 255, 64);
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
  <canvas id="can" height="100" width="100"></canvas>
  <br>
  <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value=" + " onclick="incr()" onmousedown="setTimer('incr')" onmouseup="removeTimer()">
  <input id="btnDeduct" type="button" value=" - " onclick="decr()" onmousedown="setTimer('decr')" onmouseup="removeTimer()">
  <select id="hundred" onchange="setHundred()">
    <option value=0> 0 </option>
    <option value=100> 100 </option>
    <option value=-100> -100 </option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: sir i try like this i want to happen not onmouseover only but in both onclick and onmouse over

Comment: @ChathurangaNanayakkara why would you like to incr or decr during onclick and onmouseover? if in that case, onclick event is enough

Comment: how can it be clicked without the mouse being over?

Comment: @theAlexandrian exactly, but there is 1 possibility, if you focus the button and pressed enter but it's a different approach.

Comment: i want to change the count continously while pressing mouse button on + and - that is what i need to do

Comment: that's why I am confused about the question XD

Comment: @Dencio Yes sir your anwer is correct for my question.. and my task need some more improvement in my code..

Comment: @ChathurangaNanayakkara Man, I tried to update the code and as you like it would increment if click pressed. Please try the snippet

Comment: @Dencio  Sir.. Do I have to change that problem ?

Comment: @ChathurangaNanayakkara Did you try the code above? If it is working for you then its okay.